# Power law representation of the delta distribution

Tags: distribution-theory

In a paper I am reading, the authors claime that by invoking the power law representation of the $\delta$ distribution this gives

$$
\delta(k) = (1/4\pi)\lim_{\tau\rightarrow 0} \tau k^{-3 + \tau}
$$

in three dimensional space.

From a naive point of view it looks as if the number 3 in the above equation corresponds to the number of dimensions such that for D dimensional space one would have

$$
\delta(k) = (1/4\pi)\lim_{\tau\rightarrow 0} \tau k^{-D + \tau}
$$

I am not familiar with this representation of the $\delta$ distribution, so can somebody explain to me how this representation can be derived generally for D dimensional space?

Comment: The factor would be the area/volume of the unit sphere, which in the case $d = 3$ happens to be $4\pi$. I don't know whether further adjustments would be necessary for other dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, in each dimension $D\geqslant1$,
$$
\delta(k)=\lim_{\tau\to0}\frac1{\sigma_D}\tau\|k\|^{-D+\tau},
$$
where $\sigma_D$ denotes the surface of the unit sphere $S^{D-1}$ in dimension $D$. To check this, recall that, if $k=ru$ with $r\gt0$ and $u$ in $S^{D-1}$, the element of volume is 
$$
\mathrm dk=r^{D-1}\mathrm dr\,\mathrm ds_D(u),
$$
Thus, for every $R\gt0$,
$$
\iint_{B(0,R)}\frac1{\sigma_D}\tau\|k\|^{-D+\tau}\mathrm dk=\int_0^R\tau r^{-D+\tau}(r^{D-1}\mathrm dr)\int_{S^{D-1}}\frac1{\sigma_D}\mathrm ds_D(u)=R^\tau,
$$
hence, when $\tau\to0$,
$$
\iint_{B(0,R)}\frac1{\sigma_D}\tau\|k\|^{-D+\tau}\mathrm dk\to1.
$$